# Почему он пишет, что таймер не инициализирован?

Tags: java, таймер

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class starting extends JFrame{

    JLabel back, meteor, earth;
    int x = 190;

    public starting() {
        super("Space police");
        JLayeredPane lp = getLayeredPane();

        back = new JLabel();
        back.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/for_starting/back.jpg"));
        back.setBounds(0, 0, 1366, 768);
        lp.add(back, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

        meteor = new JLabel();
        meteor.setIcon (new ImageIcon("src/for_starting/asteroid.gif"));
        meteor.setBounds(x, 450, 300, 100);
        lp.add(meteor, JLayeredPane.POPUP_LAYER);

        earth = new JLabel();
        earth.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/for_starting/earth.png"));
        earth.setBounds(930, 400, 200, 200);
        lp.add(earth, JLayeredPane.POPUP_LAYER);

        Timer timer = new Timer(80, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                meteor.setBounds(x+=2, 450, 300, 100);
                if(x==666)
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        );
        timer.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Наверное потому что конструктор не вызывается. Или создай таймер глобально, а инициализируй в конструкторе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что когда метод `stop()` был вызван, таймер еще не был создан.

Для остановки таймера изнутри существует такой трюк:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, null);
timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      System.out.println("Working");
        timer.stop();
    }
});
timer.start();
for(;;); // Длы того чтобы программа не завершилась ранше времени
```

То есть сначала создается пустой таймер, а затем уже добавляется слушатель.
Данный код выведет в консоль *Working* через 1 секунду после запуска.

Comment: Что значит не был создан? Мы бы получили NPE в таком случае...не?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Да, я немного ошибся, правильнее будет сказать _не инициализирован_, т.е компилятор видит что мы обращаемся к `Timer timer;`, а не `Timer timer = new Timer(...);` и попросту не дает скомпилировать код.

Comment: А, ясно. Я думал, речь идет о рантайме...